# Find two partitions P,Q of $[a,b]$ such that $||Q||<||P||$ but $\underline{S}(f,P)=\underline{S}(f,Q)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I'm trying to answer the following exercise:

> Give an example of a bounded function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, with two partitions P,Q of $[a,b]$ such that $||Q||<||P||$ but $\underline{S}(f,P)=\underline{S}(f,Q)$

Where $||Q||$ is the norm of Q and $||P||$ is the norm of P; $\underline{S}(f,P)$ and $\underline{S}(f,Q)$ are the inferior sums.

I've tried to solve it with the following attempts, but with none of them I got that $\underline{S}(f,P)=\underline{S}(f,Q)$:

$f: [0,2]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=e^x \: \forall x\in [0,2] $; with the partitions $P=\{0, \frac{1}{2}, 1, \frac{3}{2}, 2\}$ and $Q=\{0, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}, 1, \frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2}, \frac{7}{4}, 2\}$, where it's clear that $||Q||=\frac{1}{4}<\frac{1}{2}=||P||$, but $\underline{S}(f,P)<\underline{S}(f,Q)$

And I got to the same result with this attempt:
$f: [0,2]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=x^2 \: \forall x\in [0,2] $; with the partitions $P=\{0, \frac{1}{2}, 1, \frac{3}{2}, 2\}$ and $Q=\{0, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}, 1, \frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2}, \frac{7}{4}, 2\}$, where it's clear that $||Q||=\frac{1}{4}<\frac{1}{2}=||P||$, but $\underline{S}(f,P)\neq\underline{S}(f,Q)$

I know these are really simple functions but I was trying to see if with those I could get to some function that worked (which it's clear it didn't), and I'm guessing that only certain functions are capable of doing so.

If you could help me with an example I'd appreciate it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just use a constant function? For an increasing function like $e^x$ it is going to be difficult (maybe impossible), since finer partitions typically lead to better approximations to the integral. For a constant function, any partition is as good as any other. Otherwise you could try something periodic, and try to exploit the repetition in values.

Comment: Is there another constant function different than $f(x)=0$ that could be useful? Okay, I'll try also with periodic functions, do you have in mind any domain in particular that could be helpful?

Comment: Any constant function and any two partitions $P, Q$ will work because for a constant function, every lower sum gives the exact value of the integral.

Comment: Generally $\underline{S}(f, P)\le \underline{S}(f,Q)$ if $Q$ is a refinement of $P$.

Answer (score 1):

Generally $\underline{S}(f, P)\le \underline{S}(f,Q)$ if $Q$ is a refinement of $P$. But for some special partitions $P$ and $Q$ and some function $f$, $\underline{S}(f, P)$ and $\underline{S}(f,Q)$ may be the same. For example, let
$$ f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \frac12 \text{ if }x\in[0,\frac12]\\
\frac32 \text{ if }x\in(\frac12,1]\\
1 \text{ if }x\in(1,\frac32]\\
2 \text{ if }x\in(\frac12,2]
\end{array}\right. $$
be a piecewise constant function. Then for the partitions $P=\{0, \frac{1}{2}, 1, \frac{3}{2}, 2\}$ and $Q=\{0, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}, 1, \frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2}, \frac{7}{4}, 2\}$, we have
$$ \underline{S}(f,P)=\frac12\cdot\frac12+\frac32\cdot\frac12+1\cdot\frac12+2\cdot\frac12=\frac52 $$
and
$$ \underline{S}(f,Q)=\frac12\cdot\frac14+\frac12\cdot\frac14+\frac32\cdot\frac14+\frac32\cdot\frac14+1\cdot\frac14+1\cdot\frac14+2\cdot\frac14+2\cdot\frac14=\frac52. $$